# Will this return keyword exit from the method of if/else block?

Tags: ruby

I have a method that looks like this and I'm unsure if using this `return` method will exit out of the method or `if/else` block. Can someone explain to me what would happen in this scenario. If I reach the conditions that get to `return` will it exit out and hit `method_I_want_to_avoid`?

```
def buy_another_pet(owner)
  if owner.has_pets?
    if owner.pets.is_healthy?
       if owner.pets.count == 3
          # Don't buy a pet
       else
          # buy another pet
          return
       end
    end
    # =====Will my return keyword avoid the below method=====?
    method_I_want_to_avoid
  end
end
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: it will exit from the buy_another_pet method. If you want to skip that if/else you should use break instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I reach the conditions that get to `return` will it exit out and hit
>   `method_I_want_to_avoid`?

No. `return` exits the method, not `if`/`else` block.